# Freemarker + Spring NoSuchBeanDefinitionException but Bean defined

Tags: spring, freemarker

I am trying to integrate **Freemarker with Spring MVC** but when I run my app on Tomcat I receive following exception:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Must define a single FreeMarkerConfig bean in this web application context (may be inherited): FreeMarkerConfigurer is the usual implementation. This bean may be given any name.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfig] is defined
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.autodetectConfiguration(FreeMarkerView.java:177)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.initServletContext(FreeMarkerView.java:149)

.
.
.

It's very strange because I have a FreeMarkerConfig bean defined in my app context . Here is my web.xml and mvc-config.xml files:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>Practic</display-name>

<!--
    - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
    - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!--
    - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

mvc-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.zimny.spring" />

<bean id="freemarkerConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Have anyone an idea for solve this issue?

Comment: What do you have in application-config.xml? Make sure FreeMarkerViewResolver isn't being loaded in there as well. Try enabling debug logging on org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory to see if the bean gets created.